# Installing libssh2-1.8.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, apt

I need to install the latest release of `libssh2` listed in [this repository](https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2/releases)  onto an Ubuntu 16.04 VM on Microsoft's Azure Cloud. Unfortunately, the latest released version I can install from apt-get is 1.5.0.

I need an easily reproducible method of installing this specific release onto the VM. I currently have a script that download's the tarball from github, unpacks, and builds from source via autotools.

I was wondering if there was a way to setup a pre build mirror or something that I could use to install the binaries from apt-get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest option here is to install the necessary packages from 17.10 or 18.04; you’ll need

- [`libssh2`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libssh2)
- [`libgcrypt20`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libgcrypt20)
- [`libgpg-error0`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libgpg-error)

I would install those using `dpkg -i`, but if you really want to use `apt`, you could either add the 17.10 repositories with suitable pinning, or create your own repository with those three packages using `apt-ftparchive` or `reprepro`.

Comment: `dpkg -i` is fine, in my script I would need to first download the deb files from launchpad from something like `wget` correct? And then simply run `dpkg -i whatever_library.deb`?

Comment: That’s it, yes — download the files using `wget` and then install them using `dpkg -i`, all three in the same command.